# Redirecting favicoin file in root directory gives a 404 error

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have added `favicon.ico` to root dir. There is WP installed on my site, and all the permalinks are set to have `/` trailing slash appear at the end. Now I want to achieve the same with `favicon.ico`.

This is the code I am using in my `.htaccess` but it is returning 404 error.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/favicon\.ico$

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /favicon.ico/ [L,R=301]
```

Any help?

Not sure why it returns such an error instead of just putting `/` at the end of the URL.

Comment: But why? That doesn't make much sense. "permalinks" are your public facing page URLs that are shared and indexed. Whereas `favicon.ico` is a static asset (a physical file), a resource used by your page and is not a public facing URL (at least not one that you should be concerned about). Presumably you are not trying to append slashes to other static assets (images, CSS, JS, etc.)? Or are you?! A request for `/favicon.ico/` (with a trailing slash) will naturally result in a 404, so it would need to be "corrected" (in `.htaccess`).